# android:google-code droidreader forceclose error

Tags: android, forceclose, pdf-reader, google-code

m using DroidReader project to display the PdfFiles.When i execute my project i am getting force close error like this

```
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at de.hilses.droidreader.DroidReaderActivity.onCreate(DroidReaderActivity.java:108)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library pdfrender not found
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  at de.hilses.droidreader.PdfRender.<clinit>(PdfRender.java:111)
07-24 20:13:26.694: E/AndroidRuntime(286):  ... 14 more
```

Help Me please

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do not have add the `.so` file with name `pdfrender`.

You can find .so files in [this](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/downloads/detail?name=droidreader-0.5.apk&can=2&q=) apk file.

Open .apk file with a zip tool. and copy the content of `lib` folder in your `libs`.

Comment: @moshin thanks dude.. yu solved my problm.. but aftr i click on welcome dialgue box in emulator it redirects to clank screen.. can yu tell me how to load Pdf files prorammatically..

Comment: I have not use this library. So I can't tell you much about it. but you need to do some thing here http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/source/browse/trunk/src/de/hilses/droidreader/DroidReaderActivity.java I guess